# Standard Thick Film Chip Resistor datasheets not mentioning storage temperature

Tags: resistors, components, datasheet, temperature, device-characteristics

I am looking for alternatives for a **120ohm 5% 1206 standard thick film chip resistor**. I have noticed some MFRs (KOA speer, Vishay, Bourns) do not always detail the storage temperature in their datasheets.

For example, I am yet to find it for **PN: RK73H2BTTD1200F** (Which I realise is a 1% not 5% tolerance part, by the way).

When MFRs do quote the storage temp, it seems to be approx. 5°C - 40°C. It seems odd not to mention it as it could be assumed if no storage temp is stated it is the same as the operating temp.

Unless there is an overriding set of assumed standard temperatures for the manner in which various components should be stored that I am unaware of?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the storage temperature is more to do with the materials of the packaging than the device; in particular regarding moisture ingress.  There is lots of literature about storage of integrated circuits, and I expect many of the parameters of that affect passives in the same way.  Solderability, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manufacturers don’t *have* to provide any particular information in any particular form, and there are certainly variations. For example, a Chinese manufacturer may supply only a sketchy data sheet, but serious customers would get a many-page document which details behaviour. Sometimes repetitive data for manufacturers is provided in application manuals or other documents that cover a range or ranges of products.

For the small-scale user, you can simply avoid those manufacturers who make the information you need hard to access. Or you can dig further in their website. Or you can contact the manufacturer themselves or try their forums in which another user or a representative may answer. Or may not.

Storage conditions, for example, will affect solderability.

[Here](https://www.koaspeer.com/pdfs/General%20Precaution%20&%20Terms.pdf) is some additional data from KOA:

> Storage • Store KOA products in dust-free areas and keep them away
> from extreme temperatures; moisture; condensation; direct sunlight;
> salt-water breezes; corrosive gases such as SO2, H2S, Cl2, NH3, NO2,
> etc.; or fumes from lubricating oil. Use desiccants if necessary. •
> Please contact KOA for conditions and length of storage.

I can imagine business reasons why they might not want to be too specific publicly
on exact storage time limits.